# Finding limits of a function

Tags: calculus, limits

How do i move forward with finding this limit. I did half of it but got stuck with the other half. I only want to understand to steps and procedure in solving it. Thanks

$$\lim_{x\to (-3)^-}\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2-9}}=\left(\lim_{x\to(-3)^-}x\right)\left(\lim_{x\to(-3)^-}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-9}}\right)=(-3)\left(\lim_{x\to(-3)^-}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-9}}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

Do it this way:

$$\lim_{x\to (-3)^-}\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2-9}}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to (-3)^-}\frac{x}{\sqrt{-x+3}}\cdot\lim_{x\to (-3)^-}\frac{1}{\sqrt{-x-3}}$$
$$=\frac{-3}{\sqrt{3+3}}\cdot\lim_{x\to (-3)^-}\frac{1}{\sqrt{-x-3}}$$

The final limit does not exist, since the denominator approaches zero and the numerator is constant. Therefore your given limit does not exist.

Your way also works. Just notice that the denominator approaches zero in your final limit and the numerator is constant. I just wanted to split as much as possible out of that limit.

The lack of limit is easily confirmed with a graph:

[image]